# Adding nature to existing .project file in plugin development

Tags: eclipse

I want to add nature of my own created plugin to .project of java when convert java project to my own project type.How can i do it?
If anyone knows the source code to write as sample,please give me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To add a nature id to a project you need the `IProject` file for the project and access the `IProjectDescription` from that:

```java
 IProject project = ... get project

 // TODO use project.hasNature("nature id") to check if already present

 IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();

 String [] natures = description.getNatureIds();

 String [] newNatures = new String[natures.length + 1];

 System.arraycopy(natures, 0, newNatures, 0, natures.length);

 newNatures[natures.length] = "nature id";

 description.setNatureIds(newNatures);

 project.setDescription(description, null);
```